# Rotate Contents of two divs every 5 seconds. like banner rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to rotate two div's every 5 seconds (like banner rotation). Second div should be hidden on page load, and after 5 seconds it should appear and the first div should be hidden.

```
<div class="banner-containner">
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Banner One">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x60?text=Banner Base">
  </div>
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Banner Two">
  </div>
</div>
```

can we toggle div with class `banner-wrapper` every 5 seconds

JSFiddle example https://fiddle.jshell.net/n811x6fe/9/

Comment: provide the css/js code where you tried to recreate this

Comment: yes use settimeout function

Comment: what is meant by banner rotation?

Comment: any example please provide that could be helpful for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope thats it what you need:

```js
var $container = $('.banner-containner');
var $bannerWrappers = $container.find('.banner-wrapper');

var idx = 0;
setInterval(function() {
 if(idx === $bannerWrappers.length) {
   idx = 0;
  }
  $bannerWrappers.hide().eq(idx).toggle();
  idx++;
}, 5000);
```

```css
.banner-containner {
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
 float:left;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
.banner-wrapper {
  float:left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  
}
.xbanner-wrapper img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.banner-wrapper:last-child{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner-containner">
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Banner One">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x60?text=Banner Base">
  </div>
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Banner Two">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or checkout [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/ge98vzxz/).

Comment: I made some changes to css to hide the second banner on load https://jsfiddle.net/ge98vzxz/3/

Answer (score 1):

this example wil rotate every `img` inside `banner-containner` `div`'s triggered every 5 seconds

```js
var deg = 0;
var wrapper = 0;
function rotatingImagesOfClass(classelement) {
  deg += 10;
if(deg == 360+10){
wrapper++;
deg = 0;
setTimeout(function(){rotatingImagesOfClass(classelement)},5000);
}else setTimeout(function(){rotatingImagesOfClass(classelement)},36);

if(wrapper == classelement.length){
wrapper = 0;
deg = 0;
}

for(var i=0;i<classelement[wrapper].getElementsByTagName("img").length;i++){
    classelement[wrapper].getElementsByTagName("img")[i].style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    classelement[wrapper].getElementsByTagName("img")[i].style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    classelement[wrapper].getElementsByTagName("img")[i].style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    classelement[wrapper].getElementsByTagName("img")[i].style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    classelement[wrapper].getElementsByTagName("img")[i].style.transform       = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';

}


}

var wrp = document.getElementsByClassName("banner-wrapper");
rotatingImagesOfClass(wrp);
```

```html
<div class="banner-containner">
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Banner One">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x60?text=Banner Base">
  </div>
  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Banner Two">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="banner-containner">
    <div class="banner-wrapper">
        <img id="bannerImage" src="http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Banner One">
        <img id="imageBase" src="http://placehold.it/200x60?text=Banner Base">
    </div>
</div>
```

Banner One is loaded as default then the others will come in their turn. 
If you have a chance to add the pathes to  the js part, you can just switch the src value of the image to be displayed. You can do it with some help of javascript.

```
var imageArray = ['http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Banner Two', 
                  'http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Banner Three',
                  'http://placehold.it/200x300?text=Banner One'];

var i = 0;


setInterval(function() {

    i = ++i % imageArray.length;

    $('#bannerImage').attr("src", imageArray[i]);
}, 5000);
```

JSFiddle: You may see the result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pgtkun5q/)